# Cannot delete Android calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I've been playing around with the Android [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) to create local (non-synced) calendars but I finally ended up with calendars with null `ACCOUNT_TYPE` and `ACCOUNT_NAME`. I can see them in:

```
getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, null, CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " IS NULL", null, null);
```

And now my Google Calendar app crashes at startup :(

I've tried to delete these dummy calendars with this piece of code (after succesfully requesting the `WRITE_CALENDAR` permission):

```
getContentResolver().delete(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " IS NULL", null);
```

but it raises the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
>   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
>   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:544)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1327)

which, I assume, is caused by their account type/name being null.

Do you have any idea of how I could get rid of them?

NB: Device's Android version is 6.0.1

Comment: `null` must not be `null`. Duh. What's unclear here? :P
 I'm having the same problem with inserting events. Google's exception messages are much less than helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what happens (note all links point to the 5.1.1 CalendarProvider, but it's probably safe to assume that it works the same in Android 6):

1. Deleting a Calendar will always pass this line:
   [CalendarProvider2.java, line 3206](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java/#3206)
2. Now in [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#3643) the method `modifyCalendarSubscription` is called for every calendar to remove (no matter how you selected them).
3. In `modifyCalendarSubscription` the provider reads the ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE column for each of these calendars and tries to create an [`Account` instance](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#4484)
4. Since the account name and type in the database are `null`, it crashes in the [`Account` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/accounts/Account.java#48) when it checks for `null` values. That's where the eException you see is actually thrown.

So, not matter how you delete the calendar, it will always fail at the `Account` constructor because the account name in the database is empty.

I didn't check it yet, but you might be able to override account name and type with an update operation. So try to set it to something that's not `null`.

If that doesn't work you either need root access to remove the calendar manually or you go to `Settings` -> `Apps` -> `All apps` -> `Calendar storage` and clear the entire calendar database (`clear data`).

**Update**

Overriding the `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE` columns will only work if you manage to match the conditions to pass this line: [CalendarProvider2.java, line 3989](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java/#3989) given that line and the conditions to get there still exists in Android 6.
It think it should work if you don't append the calendar id to the `Uri` and you don't select the calendar by their id. So making your `delete` an `update` and resetting `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE` to something that's not `null` should do the trick.

Comment: I see. Do you see any exception in the system log?

Comment: Only the one that i've put in the question

Comment: Is your device rooted? In that case you could delete the calendars from your database manually.

Comment: After overriding `ACCOUNT_TYPE` and `ACCOUNT_NAME` I could successfully delete them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I update calendars row like this:

```
private void updateNullAccount() {
        String selection = CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " IS NULL";
        Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        uri = SyncAdapter.asSyncAdapter(uri);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "NAME BITCH NAME");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        int count = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, null);
        count++;
    }
```

And after delete calendars by ACCOUNT_NAME which i have in update.

When you create local calendar you must append query parameter (as sync adapter, account name and account type) and in ContentValues add same account name and account type parameters.